# Replying positively to a business trip request email?

Tags: email, travel, business

I just joined my first company a few weeks ago and they now want me to go on a business trip. I'm super excited for the opportunity but am unsure how to respond to the email request as replying with just a "Deffo Yes!!" would be too curt I think.

Comment: Enjoy the business trips until it becomes a burden. Seeing just airports, hotel rooms and meeting rooms is far less exciting than one may think.

Answer (score 3):

'Yes, I'm fine with that, please send me the details.

Regards
Me"

Comment: I would have written”absolutely fine”, but I suppose that depends on where exactly in the world you are.

Comment: @gnasher729 my English isn't great, 'absolutely fine' would be OK as well.